# Execute Lua script

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to execute the Lua script, which is on the link: https://github.com/chris-allnutt/unit-tested-corona.

The command I am executing is: `lua main.lua`

I am getting this message:

```
lua: main.lua:3: attempt to index global 'display' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    main.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

What is my mistake (I am using Lubuntu 14.04)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error, because this is the script for [Corona SDK](https://coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/), so you need to run it from Corona SDK simulator, as it defines `display` and some other objects used in the script. When you run it with a "normal" Lua interpreter, those objects are not defined by it (as they are by the Corona simulator), so you get the error about indexing a `nil` value.

Comment: But README.md says: "You do not need the Corona SDK to run this."

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, it's because there is a mock object that is used in `test.lua` (`display = require('mocks.display')`), but `main.lua` is a standalone file that doesn't use any mocks. Either this needs to run under the Corona simulator or it needs to be used from `test.lua` only, which provides couple of mocks for the script to run.

Answer (score -1):

Did you read [the documentation](https://github.com/chris-allnutt/unit-tested-corona#get-it-running) on that page? You are trying to run the demo corona script directly instead of running `busted` on the busted test script.

You want to be running `busted test.lua`.

Comment: I have done that already! I want to run the script too. I am learning Lua, and I want to explore this code.

Comment: That is the reason why I want to understand why it is not executing with the command I tried.

Comment: You can't just run it. It isn't stock lua. It is corona code. You run it as a corona app (or whatever). If that was your actual question here you didn't indicate that very clearly.